# Getting Host Name from a httpRequest in Datapower

Tags: ibm-datapower

How to get HostName value from a Request send by client to  DataPower.In the header section i can see ip address after Enabling probe but i want the host name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the DNS static hosts or HOST alias in datapower, there you can find the host name assiciated with its IP, ot just do nslookup.